# S3 Policy to allow a user to Put, Get, Delete and modify permissions

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm working to create a policy document to allow a IAM users to S3 to a specific "blog" directory where they can create/edit/delete files as well as modify file permissions inside the bucket to global read so uploaded files can be made public on a blog. Here is what I have so far, only issue is the policy is not letting the user modify permissions.

How can this policy be updated to allow the user to modify permissions to global read access?

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::blog"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::blog/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ie, how to allow for making public.

Answer (score 3):

> only issue is the policy is not letting the user modify permissions.

Correct. You have granted only the `Put`, `Get` and `Delete` Permission. In order to provide access for manipulating the Object level permission, you need to provide **`s3:PutObjectAcl`** API access.

Check [s3:PutObjectAcl IAM Action documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingIAMPolicies.html#UsingWithS3_Actions) and [S3 PUT Object acl Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUTacl.html) for more details on how you can leverage this API.